# Using OAuth2 in Chrome extension in React

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-signin, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to get Google sign-in to work in my Chrome extension written in React. I am struggling with inability to load the script from `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`.

Here is the relevant part of `manifest.json`:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ]
},
"permissions": ["identity"],
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

When reloading the extension in `chrome://extensions`, I get the error:

```
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.
```

One old post suggested adding `'unsafe-eval'` flag, but apparently it's not valid anymore. I could not find any other solution.

How do I fix this?